# Blur MP4 video section for x seconds using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to blur out an account ID that is showing in the footer of my video for the first 47s.

I have managed to do an entire page blur for 47 seconds and blurred out the desired section for the entire video, but not managed to be able mix the two to get the desired result? Adding the `between` section to the original blurbox command keeps throwing errors.

Blurs entire video for first 48 seconds
`ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf "boxblur=enable='between(t,0,47)'" -codec:a copy blurred.mp4`

Blurs a certain segment, but for the whole video
`ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=450:200:150:1000,boxblur=10[fg];   [0:v][fg]overlay=150:1000[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart blurredsection.mp4`

How can I blur the x/y section AND only do it in the first 48 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim the cropped portion.

`ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:47,crop=450:200:150:1000,boxblur=10[fg];   [0:v][fg]overlay=150:1000:eof_action=pass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart blurredsection.mp4`

Comment: Still seems to blur the same section for the video duration, rather than the required first 47 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Blur a section for a specific time interval:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=450:200:150:1000,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,0,47)'[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=150:1000[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart blurred.mp4
```

Credit: deFeitas https://superuser.com/a/1564209

I am curious which approach is faster.